# Remove quotes from second items in nested list

Tags: python

I need to remove quotes from second items in nested list. For example, change:

```
a = [['first', '41'], ['second', '0'], ['third', '12']]
```

to:

```
[['first', 41], ['second', 0], ['third', 12]]
```

I tried

```
[map(int, [n[1]]) for n in a]
[[41], [0], [12], [0], [45], [17], [3], [10], [1], [19], [98], [0]]
```

But it removes the first element. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
a = [['first', '41'], ['second', '0'], ['third', '12']]
a = [[i[0], int(i[1])]for i in a]

>>> print a
[['first', 41], ['second', 0], ['third', 12]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[[item[0], int(item[1])] for item in a]
```

**Output:**

```
[['first', 41], ['second', 0], ['third', 12]]
```